# Как отобразить в alert текст из value input c помощю jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
HTML Код:
       <input type="text" id="email" value="Приклад: you@site.ua" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($('#email').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="email" value="Приклад: you@site.ua" />
```